# Add column based on join condition

Tags: mysql

I want to create a column with a value based on the condition of a join. Best viewed in an example:

**Table 1: Items** `user_id`, `item_id`, `item_property`

**Table 2: Items user liked** `user_id`, `item_id`

Expected result:

**Table 3: Items** `user_id`, `item_id`, `item_property`, `new_column`

Where the value of `new_column` is either `1` if the user_id, item_id pair (found in table 1) is present in the Table 2, `0` otherwise.

How can i create a MySql statement that achieves the following?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this for a given dataset of this nature:

```
create table items (
  user_id int,
  item_id int,
  item_property text
);
create table liked (
  user_id int,
  item_id int
);

insert into items values
(1, 1, 'Ball'), (1, 2, 'Bat'), (1, 3, 'Glove'),
(2, 4, 'Jar'), (2, 5, 'Cooker'), (2, 6, 'Stove'),
(3, 7, 'Ram'), (3, 8, 'CPU'), (3, 9, 'SSD');

insert into liked values 
(1, 2), (2, 6), (3, 7);
```

**Query**

```
select i.*, case when l.user_id is null then 0 else 1 end as liked
from items i
left join liked l
  on i.user_id = l.user_id
  and i.item_id = l.item_id
```

**Result**

```
| user_id | item_id | item_property | liked |
|---------|---------|---------------|-------|
|       1 |       2 |           Bat |     1 |
|       2 |       6 |         Stove |     1 |
|       3 |       7 |           Ram |     1 |
|       1 |       1 |          Ball |     0 |
|       1 |       3 |         Glove |     0 |
|       2 |       4 |           Jar |     0 |
|       2 |       5 |        Cooker |     0 |
|       3 |       8 |           CPU |     0 |
|       3 |       9 |           SSD |     0 |
```

**Recommendation**

Don't create a new table with an additional column. Just run the appropriate SQL query to get the actual fields in the table of your liking and additional derived/calculated fields.

To simulate a table, you could create a view like this:

```
create view items_liked 
as
select i.*, case when l.user_id is null then 0 else 1 end as liked
from items i
left join liked l
  on i.user_id = l.user_id
  and i.item_id = l.item_id;
```

That way, you can always run `select * from items_liked` and retrieve the data you wanted without having to create a table.

An example is available here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a4ef/1